# Calculating a mean with more recent observations with greater importance

Tags: python, numpy, weighted-average

I am building an algorithm to predict the outcomes of sporting events using the performance of previous games. For example, I might have two lists that look like this:

```
# list of game numbers
game_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

# list of points scored   
points_scored = [100, 106, 99, 106, 89, 94, 113]
```

I can easily calculate a mean using:

```
# calculate mean
mean_points_scored = np.mean(points_scored)
```

However, I want the more recent games to be weighted more heavily in the calculation of the mean. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: [numpy weighted average](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do weighted averages with [`np.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html)

```
mean_points_scored = np.average(points_scored, weights=game_number)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the weigh has to be define in a different array :

```
weights_define = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
mean_points_scored = np.average(points_scored, weights=weights_define)
```

Because the way that wilkben defined it is not accurate and too much exagerate and not mathematic at all !

You can check an Excel explaination which explained how maths really works (codes is basically math don't forget !) --> [Excel Debunk](https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/calculate-weighted-average-in-excel/)

Answer (score 1):

Definition of weights may be based on certain defined criteria as below. The factors of `x` may be changed or number of parts of weights list may vary depending on requirement. Assuming three parts `a,b,c` and `15` data points,( the factors of `x` are assumed to be larger towards end part of weights list, as it is given for `recent games` more heavy weights be given)

```
a = [(3*x) for x in range(1,6)]
b = [(4*x) for x in range(6,11)]
c = [(7*x) for x in range(11,16)]

weights_define = a+b+c

game_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
points_scored = [100, 106, 99, 106, 89, 94, 113, 112,109,111,97,95,102,107,103]

 mean_points_scored = np.average(points_scored, weights=weights_define)  
 print(mean_points_scored)
```

***Output:***

```
102.77878787878788
```